# Writing $G/[G, G]$ as a direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, modules, abelian-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be the group given by the presentation $\langle x , y , z : x^2 , y^3 , (xyz)^4 \rangle$. I would like to write $G/[G , G]$ as a direct product of cyclic groups, where $[G , G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.

I am familiar with writing (finitely generated) *abelian* groups as a product of cyclic groups using Smith normal forms, but the free group aspect of this problem is throwing me off (which I believe is the point). I am aware that the free group on a set $S$ modulo its commutator subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{|S|}$, but I am unsure of how the additional relations (such as those in the problem in question) impact things.

Obviously $G/[G , G]$ is a finitely generated abelian group, but is $G/[G , G]$ isomorphic to the abelian group, $A$, (written additively) generated by elements $a , b, c \in A$ subject to the relations $2a = 3b = 4(a + b + c) = 0$? If this is the case, then I am completely comfortable finishing off the problem and actually writing $G/[G , G]$ as a direct product of cyclic groups, but I would like some more justification as to why. If this is not the case, then what is the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: Yes; $G/[G,G]$ has the presentation you start with *together with* the relations $[x,y]=[x,z]=[y,z]=1$. So it reduces to the conditions you give.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of "justification as to why" you would be looking for?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think this is what I am looking for and along the lines of what I was thinking in the first place. The map that sends generators of a free group on $S$ to generators of $\mathbb{Z}^{|S|}$ induces an isomorphism between the free group on $S$ modulo its commutator and some relations $R$ onto $\mathbb{Z}^{|S|}$ modulo the relations corresponding to $R$.

Comment: Your comment does not seem to contain a question, so I am at a loss as to what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I had the same thought, but I guess I wanted more details as to why “reduces to the conditions [I] gave.”

Answer (score 3):

Standard general method:
Write the presentation in abelianized form in a matrix (rows for relators, columns correspond to generators):
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
2&0&0\\%
0&3&0\\%
4&4&4\\%
\end{array}\right).
$$
Calculate the Smith Normal form (also called elementary divisor normal form):
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
1&0&0\\%
0&2&0\\%
0&0&12\\%
\end{array}\right)%
$$
Thus the structure of $G/[G,G]$ is $C_2\times C_{12}$ (which is the same as the other andwer, using that $12=3\cdot 4$.

Justification for why Smith normal form works: Row transformations correspond to relator changes (replace relator by product with other), column operations to generator changes.

Answer (score 1):

The presentation of $G/[G,G]$ is achieved by adding the relations
$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1,xzx^{-1}z^{-1}=1,yzy^{-1}z^{-1}=1.$$
The commutators $xyx^{-1}y^{-1},xzx^{-1}z^{-1},yzy^{-1}z^{-1}$ and their inverses are the generators of the **normal** subgroup $[G,G]$.
Then
$$G/[G,G]\cong\langle x,y,z\ : x^2,y^3,(xyz)^4, xyx^{-1}y^{-1},xzx^{-1}z^{-1},yzy^{-1}z^{-1}\rangle.$$

This is also because the natural homomorphism
$
\langle x,y,z\ : x^2,y^3,(xyz)^4\rangle$ to
$\langle x,y,z\ : x^2,y^3,(xyz)^4, xyx^{-1}y^{-1},xzx^{-1}z^{-1},yzy^{-1}z^{-1}\rangle$ is surjective and has kernel the normal closure of $[G,G]$, which is $[G,G]$ itself.

The "abelian" presentation would be
$$\langle x,y,z:2x=0,3y=0, 4x+4y+4z=0,\\ x+y-x-y=0,x+z-x-z=0,y+z-y-z=0\rangle,$$ which can be simplified with
$t=x+y+z$ into
$$\langle x,y,t\ :\ 2x=0,3y=0, 4t=0\rangle,$$
and which is $\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_3\oplus \mathbb Z_4$

Comment: the abuse of language is the problem Mr. downvoter? here the abuse is that $x,y,z$ should be cosets modulo the $[G,G]$.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this is not the answer to my question. I am more concerned with *why* this is the abelian presentation. As I stated in my question, I have no trouble finishing off the problem once I justify why that is the abelian presentation.

Comment: @Oiler, thanks for the clarification, I added a few more details, hoping this might help you

Comment: "The normal closure of $[G,G]$"... Since $[G,G]$ is verbal, it is already normal. The only care is to note that it is *generated* by commutators, and may include elements that are not themselves commutators, but products thereof.

Comment: Agree, the elements of $[G,G]$ are *words* of the form $c_1c_2\cdots c_r$ where each $c_i$ are commutators themselves.

Comment: My point is that you mentioning "the normal closure of $[G,G]$" can be confusing, given that it is normal already (as you mentioned and even emphasized one paragraph before).

Comment: Ok, agree again. Let me add that $g[a,b]g^{-1}=[gag^{-1},gbg^{-1}]$ is useful  to justify that $[G,G]$ is normal.